# C# if / else thread interruption

Tags: c#

I'm a newbie to C#, I just came from PHP.

To be specific, let me "copy / paste" the piece of code that is hard for me to understand.

I have a function, which subtracts "year of birth" from the "current year" and returns ones updated age. Now, I need to check if the user's age less than 30 y.o. to print out "you are too young to view this page" message and then ask if he/she wants to continue answering the rest of the questions. Then we make our decision according the answer. If the answer "yes" we, as seen below, continue. Now I wonder, but what if a user says "no"? how to I interrupt the code?

For instance in PHP I used to type this - "exit()".

Thanks in advance.

```
        if (ma.HowOldImI(date1, date2) < 30)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you are too young to view this page");

            Console.WriteLine("would you like to continue the session?");

            string confirm = Console.ReadLine();

            if (confirm == "yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please type your name");
                string nm = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please type your born year");
                int ag = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

                gr.YouWereBorn(nm, ag);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are " + ma.HowOldImI(date1, date2) + " years old\n");
        }
```

Comment: To get out of a method, you "return;"

Comment: What do you mean by "how to I interrupt the code"? is this inside the main function of a console appliation? in a procedure that is called from main? what do you want to do when the code is "interrupted"?

Comment: Is the final application also going to be a Console app ?

Comment: I made a little mistake, I just mean "how do I interrupt the code". Yes, this peace of code's inside the main func. Well, I just want to print out something on console saying something like "Thank You for answering question etc.".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exit the function, just do a "return;"

e.g.

```
    if (ma.HowOldImI(date1, date2) < 30)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("you are too young to view this page");

        Console.WriteLine("would you like to continue the session?");

        string confirm = Console.ReadLine();

        if (confirm == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please type your name");
            string nm = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please type your born year");
            int ag = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            gr.YouWereBorn(nm, ag);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You are " + ma.HowOldImI(date1, date2) + " years old\n");
    }
```

If you need the current message pump to stop, just use `Application.Exit();` If you want to exit the application with an appropriate code use `Environment.Exit(0);`  [This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx) provides a decent overview of the difference between the two.

Comment: If they called the pasted code in another method, then that wouldn't exit the program.

Comment: It might, if there is no code after the method call, but who knows what his main is like.

Comment: -1: For the reasons others had said. You are assuming you are in the main method, and as the OP clearly has little experience with C# you are not going to be helping him

Comment: My day is fine, actually pretty satisfied from my Subway at lunch, thank you for asking. Anyway, you edit about using `Application.Exit()` is fine as this is probably the equivalent the OP was looking for. But this is a footnote in an otherwise vague answer. I just feel that suggesting the OP makes a return call without really explaining how that is going to effect his code is not helpful, and in my opinion that warrants a downvote. If you expand on the effects of using `return` OR remove that section completely then I would be happy to change my vote. Of course that is your decision to make

Answer (score 2):

There are few options you can take, which have already been said by other users, but my aim is to try and explain which ones are best for your situation.

Firstly, I am assuming you are working with a console application (purely based on the fact you use `Console.ReadLine()`.

With this in mind we know you have a `Main(string args[])` method laying around somewhere. So the first question is, is your code snippet used directly in this `Main()` function?

If so, then as you may already know, the program will exit once the program reaches the end of the function. However, it is useful to know that you can prematurely end the flow of any function by using a [return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) statement.

> The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it
>   appears and returns control to the calling method. It can also return
>   the value of the optional expression. If the method is of the type
>   void, the return statement can be omitted.

In this case `void` is used so you can simple use:

```
return;
```

as opposed to say, for example:

```
return "a string";
```

If you code logic is in another function (one that is called by the `main()` function) then you can not simply return from the function to end the program (although that may be the result anyway) because any further code in your main function would still need to be executed.

Other methods that have been suggest such as `Application.Exit()` and `Environment.Exit()` will give you the desired effect of ending the application, but I would suggest against using these directly as it would not give the user any nice feedback. You could however create a little wrapper function to end the application, for example:

```
public void EndApplication()
{
   Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to end the application, hit enter to say Goodbye...");
   Console.ReadLine();
   Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

That could then be called from anywhere you choose (and [here are some alternate error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28VS.85%29.aspx) if you want them).

However, I would prefer to let the application flow naturally through the `Main()` function and have your goodbye message at the end of that. Opting to use a `return;` statement inside a sub-function, for example:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
   DoMyWork();

   Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to end the application, hit enter to say Goodbye...");
   Console.ReadLine();
}

private void DoMyWork()
{
   //...

   string confirm = Console.ReadLine();

   if(confirm.ToLower() == "no")
   {
      return;//no need to continue with this function
   }

   //carry on with you logic
   Console.WriteLine("Please type your name");

   //...
}
```

Comment: Mate, thank you, thank you so much for the detailed step-by-step explanation, I really appreciate that. Like I said before, I'm a newbie, so I gotta get used to using "pplication.Exit() and Environment.Exit()" and learn them in depth.

Comment: @Akbaroff: If my answer, or any of the other ones, helped you. You should consider making whichever one you prefer as accepted. This will help to increase your reputation and allow you to do much more on the StackOverflow site. Once you have 15 rep you can even start upvoting multiple answers that you find help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at the code, if the user says no. The logic for please type name etc is skipped, and the function exits. If it does not, then do as everyone says with:

```
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code - Add return

```
    if (confirm == "yes")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please type your name");
        string nm = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please type your born year");
        int ag = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        gr.YouWereBorn(nm, ag);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: i'am happy to help you Akbaroff